# How to produce this specific list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a bit of a complicated problem. I'm trying to make a function which takes in a list of 0s and 1s and returns a list of lists. It's easiest if I just show an example

**input** :

```
[0,0,0,1,0,1]
```

**output** :

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Another example

**input** :

```
[1,0,1]
```

**output** :

```
[[0,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0]]
```

I have a solution right now, where I first produce all the the combinations and then filters out the ones that are not allowed. But this demands massive amount of memory so I'm looking for a better solution.

```
def func(input):
    A = list(itertools.product(range(2), repeat=int(len(input)+1)))

    # Filters out all the lists which have first element equal to 0 
    #  and 1s anywhere else 
    A = [item for item in A if not (item[0] == 0 \
                    and sum(item) >= 1 or item[A.index(item)+1] == 1) ]

    # Filter out all lists which has 1s at places the input does not have
    A = [item for item in action_space if not \
                    sum(np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_xor(item[1:], \
                    self.adj_mat[node.get_node_nr()]),item[1:])) > 0]

    return A
```

Comment: An inefficient but easy solution would be to `list.shuffle()` repeatedly, check if your new list is valid, and not in the 2D list already, and continue until the target number of sublists is reached

Comment: I don't see how your examples fit the explanation...

Comment: @JammyDodger please please please don't do that.

Comment: @user3483203 Hey I said it was inefficient

Comment: What would be the solution for `[1,0,0]`? `[[0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0]]`? The last element is always `[1, len(l) zeroes]`? And the "intermediates" depend on the number of ones?

Comment: Your output is *not* all combinations of the input.

Comment: define **all the combinations of the input"* How do you get from `[0,0,0,1,0,1]` to `[0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0]`? Do you mean that all elements which are `1` in the input can be either `1` or `0` in the output? If so, say that.

Comment: And some more questions: Does the order matter? If so, how is the order defined?

Comment: I didn't know how to explain it tbh, so I removed the "explanation". Seemed to just cause confusion. The input/output examples are correct.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you derive the output from the input, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of the indices to mutate, then use `itertools.product` to generate all the possible variations.

```
from itertools import product

def func(l):
    indicies = [i for i, x in enumerate(l, start=1) if x]
    prod = product([0, 1], repeat=len(indicies))
    yield [0] * (len(l) + 1)
    for variation in prod:
        temp = [1, *l]
        for index, value in zip(indicies, variation):
            temp[index] = value
        yield temp

print(list(func([0,0,0,1,0,1])))
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
print(list(func([1,0,1])))
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I see we've come to a very similar solution!

Comment: Thank you, I will test it later.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Get indices. Then take all subsets of indices to generate sublists to add to result

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

lst = [0,0,0,1,0,1]
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x == 1]
result = [[0] * (len(lst)+1)]
for element in powerset(s):
    new_element = [[0] * (len(lst)+1)]
    new_element[0][0] = 1
    for pos in element:
        new_element[0][pos+1] = int(1)
    result.extend(new_element)

print(result) # [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it later.

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.permutations`, and just prepend a 1 to each of them.

```
from itertools import permutations


def augment(xs):
    yield [0] + [0 for _ in xs]
    for x in permutations(xs):
        yield [1] + list(x)


out = list(augment([1,0,1])
```

If you'd rather write a single expression rather than a generator function, its just

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

xs = [1, 0, 1]
out = list(chain([[0] + [0 for _ in xs]], ([1] + list(x) for x in permutations(xs))))
```

Comment: I believe this is not what was asked for, judging from the test cases given.

Comment: Yes, the description of what he wants is at odds with the example output.

Comment: I'm sorry, the description is really bad. The input and output examples are much more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.product` and a generator:

```py
def get_combinations(lst):
    yield [0]*(len(lst)+1)
    idxs = [idx for idx, x in enumerate(lst) if x]
    for vals in product(*[[0, 1]]*2):
        vals_i = iter(vals)
        yield [1] + [0 if idx not in idxs else next(vals_i) for idx in range(len(lst))]
```

Then `list(get_combinations([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]))` prints

```py
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test it later.